# SetTimeout function with variable time

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to create a countdown using time values taken from a POST value. Problem is that I cannot make it work, not sure if this is even doable. Here is my code:

```
<script type = 'text/javascript'>

var tiempo =  <?php 
    $result = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    $RES = fread($result,"3");
    ?>;


function show() {
    document.getElementById("img").style.display = "block";
    setTimeout("hide()", tiempo);
}

function hide() {
    document.getElementById("img").style.display = "none";
}


   </script>
```

Comment: In your `<?php ?>` block you are not [echoing](http://php.net/echo) or [printing](http://php.net/print) anything, so nothing will appear. The resulting line will look like this: `var tiempo = ;`

Comment: You are currently reading from a file. What have you tried to do, in order to read from the POST request? Please make sure questions include what you have tried and what failed. You may find the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help article helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do `echo $RES` to print the result of `fread` which has the content of `file.txt`.
If it is a string, you should add `'` between the `<?php` tag.

```
var tiempo =  '<?php 
   $result = fopen("file.txt", "r");
   $RES = fread($result,"3");
   echo $RES;
   ?>';
```